# Excel formula to find matching part of index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working with structure like tree graph.
I have items where each one has index telling where it appears in the tree.
Then i get groups of items like this:
Item 1: A-1-1-2-1-1-1
Item 2: A-1-1-1-1-2
Item 3: A-1-1-2-1-1-2
Item 4: A-1-1-2-1

What i need to find is common part of index for each group.In this example a common part would be "A-1-1-".
Is it possible to find matching part of the string in another string using excel formulas? My collague said i'd need to make vba macro using recursion to find only part of matching string, but maybe there's simplier solution we didn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A4,LEFT(A1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))))&"*")=COUNTA(A1:A4),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))))))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: It works great!   
To be fair im not 100% sure how it works. Im a bit lost at Indexing (didnt use it very much) but i'll educate myself to understand it :)
Thank you very much for amazing solution.

Comment: `ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)))` just returns an array of sequential numbers from 1 to the length of the string.  Now that I look at it, it should be `ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)))`  I will edit.

Comment: For ExcelO365, you could use: `=LEFT(A1,MAX(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A4,LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))&"*")=COUNTA(A1:A4),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))))`. Also the only version where CSE confirmation wouldn't be necessary =)